# How can I format a partition currently mounted at filesystem root without using an external flashdrive?

Tags: partitioning, mount

I want to wipe out all my partitions and start my ubuntu from scratch. I have already formatted the partitions which were mounted at /media/user/name using disk utility. But I am unable to do so with the partition mounted at filesystem root. Please note I am not talking about the BIOS boot or EFI system partition. But the linux filesystem partition.

Comment: Why do you have the requirement "without using an external flashdrive"? What exactly did you try? How do you plan to start from scratch? This usually involves booting from a flashdrive, CD/DVD or network boot server, and you can often use the same installation media to run a live system or to make manual changes to your disk partitioning.

Comment: You have to do it externally. Or if you have another system like Windows, you could boot to that and wipe the ubuntu partitions from there. But if you are going to do a re-install then you need to use your USB drive anyway, so you may as well do everything from there.

Comment: Just install Ubuntu again. Choose the option to erase everything during install. All partitions will be erased. Trying to format the partition from which Ubuntu is running is like trying to change a tire of a car while driving it.

Comment: @user68186 I thought EFI parition and BIOS partition were responsible for the so called "car". Can't I keep running the system while formatting the filesystem partition?

Comment: No. UEFI / BIOS is like the ignition key and starter of a car. Without them a car won't start. Do you think of loosening some of the lug nuts of the wheels while driving the car? Even if you could reach the tires from the driver's seat, it would be impossible to grab the nuts while the wheels are spinning. Once the nuts are loose your car will end up in a ditch. No.